# How to create a page with certain products within a WooCommerce store?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a page on my website where I can only show certain products from my online store.
I have created a template (Specified Products) trying to add the products I want using the `ID`, and then, I have created a page called MY PRODUCTS for which I chose the template created before (Specified Products).
In it I select the products by the 'ID', I don't know if there is another way to do it.
You can see the template code and they will tell me what I'm doing wrong. The page in question shows one product per row, and it occupies the entire width of the screen.
Only the product image is displayed, occupying the entire width of the screen.

There is no way you can see the example, since I am in a Local project
Can you see the mistakes I'm making in this code?
Thank you

```
<?php
     /*
      * Template Name: Specific Products Page
      * Description: Template to display specific products from different categories
      */
    
     // Include WordPress header
     get_header();
    
     // Get products from different categories by their ID or slug
     $product_ids = array(23, 45, 67); // ID of desired products
     $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'post__in' => $product_ids,
         'posts_per_page' => -1, // Show all products
     );
    
     // Consult the products
     $products_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
     // Show products
     if ($products_query->have_posts()) :
         while ($products_query->have_posts()) :
             $products_query->the_post();
             global $product;
             ?>
             <div class="product-item">
                 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                 <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                
             </div>
             <?php
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_postdata();
     else :
         echo 'No products found.';
     endif;
    
     // Include the WordPress footer
     get_footer();
```

I did several tests, but the products always came out disproportionate.
I can show some of the tests, but I did a lot.
Something I'm not having countertop notice is not allowing me to create the layout like the WooCommerce one

```
<?php
     if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
         exit; // Exit if not accessed from WordPress
     }
    
     /*
      * Template Name: Specific Products Page
      * Description: Template to display specific products from different categories
      */
    
     // Include WordPress header
     get_header();
    
     // Get products from different categories by their ID or slug
     $product_ids = array(23, 45, 67); // ID of desired products
    
     // Show products with WooCommerce loop
     if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) {
         echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
         woocommerce_product_loop_start();
         foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
             $post_object = get_post( $product_id );
             setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
             wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
         }
         woocommerce_product_loop_end();
         echo '</div>';
     }
    
     // Restore data from the original loop
     wp_reset_postdata();
    
     // Include the WordPress footer
     get_footer();
     ?>
```

​

Answer (score 2):

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'product',
    'include' => array( 23, 45, 67 )
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Please check this link for more : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: I don't know how to implement your example @Chetansharmaphp007. I have read the documentation but I can't find a way to add it

Comment: Have you tried my code ?  Just replace it with this part in your code  // Get products from different categories by their ID or slug
     $product_ids = array(23, 45, 67); // ID of desired products
     $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'post__in' => $product_ids,
         'posts_per_page' => -1, // Show all products
     );

Comment: Thank you. I receive error on this line: `<?php echo $products->get_price_html(); ?>` ERROR: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on array in`

Comment: Please try like this or check if $products has not empty                                                                                                    
global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
echo $product->get_price_html(); //Shows the price

Comment: try to change type with post type in arguments

Comment: or you can try in this way ...                                                                                                        $product_ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
$products    = array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product_ids );                                                          After this you should check if there are value or not in $products variable

Comment: I don't really understand how to do it. Wouldn't it be better if you edited the answer and put all the code? Did you not test the code before adding the answer? Thank you

Comment: Many times I used this way, Okay will be back soon